# What can I use to fill cracks in boarded walls before painting?

Tags: walls

My house was built in the 30's. and the walls are tongue and groove. Over the years cracks have formed between the slats. Is there a compound similar to joint compound that I can get to fill them before painting?

Comment: Can you post a picture?

Comment: Cracks, or gaps? Wood is generally not considered a suitable substrate for coating with joint compound. You'd want to overlay 1/4" drywall.

Comment: Also, it's common to paint walls while retaining the wood plank texture. If that's undesirable, you may need to overlay.

Comment: I would suggest paintable caulk.

Comment: Sounds as if you've got 'ship lap' which is to die for.  Why do you feel that you need to hide those horizontal lines?  Got to use drywall to do that other wise leave those joints alone to use for texture on your walls.  I think it is always better to go with the flow of what material you already have and ship lap is such a great wall.  Won't find THAT in today's construction. I'd use an air compressor and sand blast the wall to get rid of built up crap others have used and then paint or stain.

Comment: @stormy - I have similar walls to what the OP describes in my 1900's cottage - not ship-lap, but tongue-and-groove. Just like floor-boards, but a bit thinner and nailed to the wall studs. They've shrunk a bit in the last century so I'm squeezing caulk into the gaps before re-painting while still leaving the horizontal tongue-and-groove pattern.

Comment: Nothing will withstand the movement caused by swelling and shrinking that occurs with this type wood. Overlay with Sheetrock or paint with no crack filling joint compounds wil fail with in a few months at most

Comment: Is there a problem with the joints in the tongue and groove?  Air being able to pass through a wall is sometimes a good thing.  Caulking with all the different cool types never solves this kind of problem...Covering with sheet rock would be the easiest way to make the wall a normal wall not influenced by temperature.  Ventilation is a good thing for walls.  Just not direct from outside to inside...I agree Kris...

Comment: Voting to close as unclear. We still don't know what the situation is, and OP has vanished.

Answer (score 2):

Wood moves.  Fact of of life.  Engineered wood (plywood, OSB, hardboard) moves less, but it moves.

In the 30's they were still using first growth lumber.  Might be worth stripping and then staining, although that is a lot of work.  If it's painted they may be lead based paint.  Research that.  Do NOT let lead paint get airborne (don't sand)

Ok.  You don't like wood.  Cover with drywall.  I don't like quarter inch -- I'm not good enough to get it on flat, and it's not a lot cheaper than half inch.  However it's lighter. While you're at that:  Shine a bright light at a shallow angle:  Is the present wall flat?

You will need to put box extenders on any wiring.

You may want consider taking the T&G off and bringing the wire up to code.  Probably knob and tube that old.  You may also find you have no insulation in the walls.